# Is it possible to make isearch to recognize space as other completion engines do?

Tags: isearch

For instance, in helm,
`word1 word4`.

It would match a line with
`word1 word2 word3 word4`.

Would it be possible to emulate that behavior with isearch?

Isearch doesn't match the line because it tries to find `word1 word4`.
ie. the whitespace is part of the search query (it seems you can relax it a bit using an option).

For instance,

1. `word4 word1` line wouldn't match in isearch.
   to support it, it would need something like `grep word1 | grep word4`
2. `word1 word4` line wouldn't match.
   to support it, it would need something like `grep word1 .* word4`

Wonder any of these are possible with either isearch or isearch-occur

- edit

so 1 doesn't seem possible with standard isearch
but 2 is

```
  (setq search-whitespace-regexp ".*?")
  (setq isearch-lax-whitespace t)
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't make clear what text would **not** match input of `word1 word4`. So answers that tell you how to make `word1 word4` match that line could be all over the place. Please specify *exactly* what you want to match, as the only possible match(es).

Comment: I did change, hope it is better now

Comment: Still unclear. What is it that you do *not* want to match. Saying "wouldn't match" isn't clear - does that mean that you do *not* want to match an occurrence of `word1 word4`, in addition to matching `word1 word2 word3 word4`? If not, just search with `C-M-s `word1.*word4`. There's far too much that's unclear in your question. You need to specify the behavior you want, as opposed to what you don't want.